# Attempting to eliminate runTest method requirement

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working on a large codebase written in Python. The main developer of the code is no longer working for the company.

The code has an automated suite, which instead of using pytest autodiscovery is manually specifying what tests to run in a series of TestClass.runTest(self) methods.

I'd like to eliminate these runTest methods and use autodiscovery, so I can parallelize the tests using the pytest-xdist plugin.

If I just eliminate all the runTest methods and the things that appear to be calling them, I get a bunch of:

```
_____________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of TestRepo.test_checkin_checkout ______________________________________________________________
[gw5] linux2 -- Python 2.7.15 /usr/bin/python

self = <tests.repo_test.TestRepo testMethod=runTest>, args = ('test_checkin_checkout',), kwargs = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>       super(TestRepo, self).__init__()

repo_test.py:31: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
base/base_repo_test.py:15: in __init__
    super(BaseRepoTests, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
E   ValueError: no such test method in <class 'tests.repo_test.TestRepo'>: runTest
```

I've also tried to Google (a lot) about runTest methods (and methodName, which appears to be an argument to `TestFoo.__init__(self, methodName='runTest')`, and I'm not finding much.

In the interest of understanding when a runTest method *is* required, I attempted to put together a little test code to see if I could get it to *depend* on a runTest method, but that's not working.  The code is autodiscovered anyway.

Can anyone please tell me how a runTest method becomes required?

Here's the little test module that *fails* to depend on runTest:

```
"""Unit test for tf module."""


import unittest

import tf


class TestPc(unittest.TestCase):
    """Unit tests for tf module."""

    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        """Initialize."""
        super(TestPc, self).__init__(methodName)

    def setUp(self):
        """Set up for tests - but not really."""
        super(TestPc, self).setUp()
        self.foo = 'bar'

    def test_add_1(self):
        """Test tf.add_1."""
        assert tf.add_1(2) == 3

    def test_add_2(self):
        """Test tf.add_2."""
        assert tf.add_2(5) == 7

    def test_mult_3(self):
        """Test tf.mult_3."""
        assert tf.mult_3(11) == 33

    def runTest(self):
        """Run the tests."""
        self.test_add_1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm hoping to get that little test module to only run test_add_1().  test_add_2() and test_mult_3() should not be run.  I know I can use a decorator for this, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Which Python version are you using because this bug was fixed in Python 3.2: "- `unittest.TestCase` can be instantiated without a method name; for simpler
  exploration from the interactive interpreter."

Comment: Please post the complete error message; aside from that, the code from the question doesn't reproduce the error when running with `pytest`, neither with Python 2.7 nor with Python 3.

Comment: This is on Python 2.7 (CPython 2.7), but I'm working on making it 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code of the `unittest`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.7/Lib/unittest) module it appears to me that the "runTest" method should be used exactly for manual control, direct test execution, a simpler way to have a test case with only one test scenario or as a general test wrapper that is defined at runtime.
Also, as noted by @Laurent LAPORTE on his comment, it is used as a sentinel value to allow a `TestCase` to be instantiated without a method name for using with interactive interpreter and debugging.

It is ignored when using test discovery if there are any other tests in the class ([this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/742b16edd692f58a06e0d55bedfffb77a112b205/Lib/unittest/loader.py#L91)).

Since you are getting that error when using test discovery, it means that somewhere on some test or on some `load_tests` package function a test case class is being instantiated directly (like `TestPc()`)

A good example of a use case of the `runTest` function is to wrap a test function in a `TestCase`, this use case is even implemented on the `unittest` module as [`FunctionTestCase`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/742b16edd692f58a06e0d55bedfffb77a112b205/Lib/unittest/case.py#L1368).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that runTest is a sort of fallback if no test_* methods are found, but for some reason the large codebase is using runTest despite being able to autodiscover multiple test_* methods.

Comment: Then I have no idea why it is being used.